# Is having multiple activites when building a Android application normal?

Tags: android, user-interface

I know this may seem like a really noob question but I just happen to wonder as I was building a little application I decided to work on.

As I continued to work on the application I have realized that I had 4 activities in total, is this normal? Is is too much? Is there ever more?

And I understand a lot of people will say 'It depends on the app' but is there ever a time where certain apps have more than 4 activities?

Is there a downside to having multiple activities?
I just started working on Android a few months back so respond as I have no idea about Android, please.

Thank you.

Comment: It’s perfectly normal!

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but I was not 100% sure.  Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this normal?

Having more than one activity is perfectly normal.

> is there ever a time where certain apps have more than 4 activities?

Sure:

- Adobe Acrobat 16.0 has 19 activities
- Amazon Kindle 4.22.0.165 has 91 activities
- Firefox 45.0.2 has 126 activities
- Stack Exchange 1.0.85 has 16 activities
- [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](https://commonsware.com/Android) 7.2 has 10 activities

and so on. Personally, I think the 91 for Amazon Kindle is a bit much, and similarly for the 126 used by Firefox 45.0.2, but that's just me.

> Is there a downside to having multiple activities?

It is important that you have a clear plan for how the user is going to navigate through the various parts of your app. Lots of activities make some forms of navigation (e.g., nav drawer) a bit more difficult.

If you think about Web apps, having one dominant activity with lots of fragments or other replaceable bits of UI would be akin to the single-page Web app approach. Even with those apps, usually there are other pages involved (settings, help/about, etc.). Having lots of activities is akin to having a Web app with lots of linked pages/forms. Neither is wrong. They each have their pros and their cons.

Comment: Wow.  You have answered my question in full detail.  126 activities though? That sounds crazy but I understand the point you are making.  And I defiantly understand that my 4 activities is no harm, and that was what I was worried about most.  I will surely do a little bit more research but you sir gave me a great starting point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple activities are perfectly normal.  There is no arbitrary limit.  As their name indicates they tend to represent different activities (i.e., screens) within your application.

As you progress with your Android knowledge you should also investigate fragments.  Fragments behave like a nested activity.  Each fragment can define its own layout and manage its own lifecycle.  When a fragment specifies its own layout, it can be configured with other fragments to adapt to a variety of screen sizes (e.g., phone vs. tablet).

Comment: Yeah I totally understand.  I did spend a little time learning about fragments in my personal time and also during college, but we only spent a couple of days on it.  But since we are on topic of Fragments, they may not even be included in this answer but I'll shoot anyway.  Question:  If i decide to create an application where the user uses swipe tabs to swipe between screens, so just left and right.  Each tab has it's own java class which extends Fragment class.  But a lot of the stuff I want to do in this classes I must extend Activity but I cannot as you cannot extends 2 classes.

Comment: Continued* My question is, how can I re-design the navigation so that the user can still swipe left and right through each screen but that I can extend Activity on each of these classes instead of Fragment?  I may be talking nonsense now but hopefully you understand what I am trying to achieve.  Even I create a class for each of the screens and extend Activity, how do I enable swiping left and right without extending Fragment class?